# Installation of RETScreen Expert software

Tags: exception

> i am trying to install RETScreen Expert software but while installation its giving the following problem. i am using windows Vista.

Exception. System.IO.FileFormatException
Message.The image format is unrecognised

Source . Presentation Core.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The UI of the installation program didn't launch properly on your computer. You can install RETScreen Expert in silent mode by using the "-q" switch from the command line.

You should probably contact their customer support directly by visiting their website or sending them an email.

(disclaimer: I work for NRCan on RETScreen)